# Devise hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a devise model

migration is:

```
t.string :provider, null: false, default: "email"
t.string :uid, null: false, default: ""

## Database authenticatable
t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

## Recoverable
t.string   :reset_password_token
t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

# etc...
```

When I do `rails c` and type `User` there I get a huge list of its columns

```
User(id: integer, provider: string, uid: string, encrypted_password: 
string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, 
remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer,
current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, 
current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, 
confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, 
confirmation_sent_at: datetime, unconfirmed_email: string...
```

But when I type `u = User.find(1)`. It has only some columns `id, provider, uid, created_at, updated_at`.

When I do `u.to_json` I get `{"id":1,"provider":"email","uid":"mymail@mail.com","name":"Name","surname":"Surname","email":"mymail@mail.com","created_at":"2016-08-07T18:27:24.186Z","updated_at":"2016-08-07T18:34:48.647Z"}`.

It ignores fields like `confirmed_at`, `confirmation_sent_at` etc...

So, I want to add some more "hidden" columns in my model. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Devise has `BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION` constant for it. Check it in source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L59

You can hide columns from serialization in your Devise config at `config/initializers/devise.rb` with line like:

`Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION.concat [:column_1, :column2]`

Comment: Ah! Good find. It was the first thing that puzzled me when I installed Devise.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different fields in your database? (`condirmed_at`, `confirmation_send_at` etc..)

Something like that:

```
 t.string   :confirmation_token
 t.datetime :confirmed_at
 t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
```

And others ?

Check your schema file (db/schema.rb)

Comment: I have these fields in my database. And I can access them using `User.find(1).confirmation_token`. But when I do `User.find(1).to_json` it ignores these fields. Btw, I'm using rails 5.0

Comment: This is not a bug, this is some feature in rails 5, i guess they save something like `serializator`, which ignores these fields. And I'm curious to know how they do it :)