# Devise why sign_in_count in BLACKLIST_SERIALIZATION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to know why sign_in_count and current_sign_in_at of :trackable option are blacklisted by devise, I understand that encrypted_password is blacklisted but sign_in_count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were added to an internal constant, `BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION`, to provide more secure defaults for Devise models.

The array can be modified to remove those attributes that you need from the blacklist.

According to this answer right [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411124/5012862) Devise has `BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION` constant for this purpose. Check it in the source code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L59

You are advised not to modify it according to this [comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/5108#issuecomment-519900672) by one of the contributors of devise.

I don't think `BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION` should be something encouraged to be modified. It's not a configuration option, but an internal constant to provide more secure defaults for Devise models.